# iOS TableView Sorting - not for all rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to sort rows in my UITableView, but not all rows. For example:

I have 2 "Header" Rows and a "Footer Row".  These have the following properties:

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Now I'll want to sort the other rows (red rows here).

[image]

But, the solution should be unable to move any red row OUTSIDE the SUBHEADER and FOOTER row.

When I set:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
   return true
}
```

And exclude here HEADER / SUBHEADER and FOOTER row - they are still unable to move, but I am able to move (for example) the first red row between HEADER and SUBHEADER.

Any idea how can I prevent row sorting outside the "red" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`tableView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:toProposedIndexPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614953-tableview) to dictate that a move to an undesirable place is impossible.

For example, if the `to` proposed index path is illegal, return the `from` index path to force the row back where it came from.

Comment: Thanks again - was not sure that there where any delegate methods to check that case out. I will try it out